# How do you deal with AMPscript errors?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, error

Is there a `try/catch` function in AMPscript?  If not, how do you deal with errors in your code?

I have a code that may break when using `lookUpRows`, but i want it to do it again, but with another id. It breaks on 5th line

```
%%[

FOR @rowIterator = 1 TO 12 DO 

    set @productsRowCount = RowCount(@productRows)
    set @productRow = Row(@productRows, random(1, @productsRowCount))
    set @productId = v(field(@productRow, "product_id"))
    set @product = Row(lookUpRows("All Products", "product_id", @productId),1)

    IF v(field(@product, "state")) != "published" THEN 

        set @productRow = Row(@productRows, random(1, @productsRowCount))
        set @productId = v(field(@productRow, "product_id"))
        set @product = Row(lookUpRows("All Products", "product_id", @productId),1)
        IF v(field(@product, "state")) != "published" THEN 
            set @productRow = Row(@productRows, random(1, @productsRowCount))
            set @productId = v(field(@productRow, "product_id"))
            set @product = Row(lookUpRows("All Products", "product_id", @productId),1)
        ENDIF
        IF v(field(@product, "state")) != "published" THEN 
            set @productRow = Row(@productRows, random(1, @productsRowCount))
            set @productId = v(field(@productRow, "product_id"))
            set @product = Row(lookUpRows("All Products", "product_id", @productId),1)
        ENDIF
    ENDIF

    set @publishedProducts = Concat(@publishedProducts,@productId,"|")

NEXT @rowIterator

]%%
```

Comment: You don't need to use the `v()` function inside an AMPscript blocks.  You can just reference the `@variables` by themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is out of context a bit, I had to make some assumptions - but the two best ways I can think of to do it are by looking up based on 'State' equaling 'published' in your initial lookup, removing the possibility that you will ever get any non-published products.  Or by using a do/while SSJS loop mixed with your AMPscript to ensure you always return 12 products.

Choice 1: (with an updated lookup statement)

```
set @publishedProductsRows = lookUpRows("All Products", "state", "published")
set @productsRowCount = RowCount(@publishedProductRows)

IF @productsRowCount > 0 THEN

    FOR @rowIterator = 1 TO 12 DO 

        set @productRow = Row(@publishedProductRows, random(1, @productsRowCount))
        set @productId = field(@productRow, "product_id")

        set @publishedProducts = Concat(@publishedProducts,@productId,"|")

        ENDIF

    NEXT @rowIterator

ENDIF
```

Choice 2: (combining AMPscript and SSJS do/while)

```
%%[
/* Your Previous Code */
set @productsRowCount = RowCount(@productRows)
]%%

<script runat="server">
var count = 0;

do {
</script>

%%[
    set @productRow = Row(@productRows, random(1, @productsRowCount))
    set @productId = v(field(@productRow, "product_id"))
    set @product = Row(lookUpRows("All Products", "product_id", @productId),1)

    IF field(@product, "state") != "published" THEN 

]%%

<script runat="server">
        var count += 1;
</script>

%%[
        set @publishedProducts = Concat(@publishedProducts,@productId,"|")

    ENDIF
]%%

<script runat="server">
} while (count < 12);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `try`- which is not available in AmpScript, why not create a condition on [RowCount](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/rowcount.htm)?

```
set @products = lookUpRows("All Products", "product_id", @productId)
IF RowCount(@products) = 0 THEN 
set @products = lookUpRows("All Products", "product_id", @productId2) 
ENDIF
set @product = Row(@products,1)
```

In this case, you get a second chance, where you can do a lookup with another value of Product ID, if your first attempt returns an empty result.